# How to make 4 channel image by extracting 4 channels from different color space?

Tags: image, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have extracted four channels from different color spaces and then want to combine the h,s, cb and cr channels. For this, I have converted them into a list and then appended them all one by one. Again I have converted the final list into a numpy array. But, the shape shows (4,224,224). This problem is basically append of four numpy 2D array, so that the final result will be (224,224,4) shape output.

```
img = cv2.imread(img_path)    
hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
h, s, v = hsv_img[:, :, 0], hsv_img[:, :, 1], hsv_img[:, :, 2]

darkYCB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCrCb)
y, cb, cr = darkYCB[:, :, 0], darkYCB[:, :, 1], darkYCB[:, :, 2]
```

How will I make them into 4 channel image/numpy2D_array?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.stack(list_of_images_2d, axis=-1)`

```
four_images = [np.random.random((100, 100)) for _ in range(4)]

stacked_images = np.stack(four_images, axis=-1)
print(stacked_images.shape)
```

```
(100, 100, 4)
```

Comment: @Mohiuddin show me how you do this, my code works - lets find why yours not

Comment: Yah, it really works for my small example.

Comment: stacked_images = np.stack((a,b,c,d), axis=-1) this have worked

Comment: that's basically the same as the answer, just using tuple instead of list :)